# Tableau Server- how to change discreate number to percentages?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a column in the table with discrete numbers, and can't find anywhere how to change format to percantages.. only to string,data,etc. In Tableau Desktop I know it is done by clicking on format, but here I don't see that option. Is it even possible to do in tableau server?

Comment: Have you tried editing the sheet on the server, it does have a Format option,  that could be used?

Comment: Tableau format allows you to format any *numbers* as percentages. But it won't let you format *strings* as percentages. You might need to convert the column to a numeric type or write a function that converts numeric values in it to a number.